# Java android frame layout

Tags: java, android

I want to do this : [image]

I did this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_aplication_settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#e2e2e2"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.smok.maps.AplicationSettings">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textSync"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/sync" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textSync">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/actual"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/actual" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/count" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/actual2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="min" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/line1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:button="@xml/setting_checkbox"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/point" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="@string/show_choose_point" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lin2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:button="@xml/setting_checkbox"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/sync" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/sync_request" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lin3"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:button="@xml/setting_checkbox"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/show_chooce" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/show_choosen_points" />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lin5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lin4"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:button="@xml/setting_checkbox"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="center" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/position2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="@string/current_location" />

            </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_bt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="@xml/roundedbutton"
            android:text="@string/back" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </View>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confirm_bt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="@xml/roundedbutton"
            android:text="@string/save" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't have idea how I can do border. I want to do a border and in the middle I want to have place to put text.This same how is in the screen. This look like a frame which have a text. Now I have onli text and I don not how I can create a frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is demo of your requirement.

1) You need to create a border.xml. Put this in your drawable folder. Add the following code in border.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:shape="rectangle">

    <!--stroke width and color-->

    <stroke

        android:width="2dp"

        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <!-- corner radius-->

    <corners

        android:radius="5dp" />

    <!--paddings-->

    <padding

        android:bottom="1dp"

        android:left="1dp"

        android:right="1dp"

        android:top="1dp" />

</shape>
```

2) Here is the layout.xml put the background to a linearlayout accordingly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="bd.com.tahsin.myapplicationnavgroup.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_border_help">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MENU_BOCZNE"
        android:background="@color/background_floating_material_light"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

3) And finally the screen-shot:

[image]

Hope, this will help a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="15dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp">

                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="TEST"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="   MENU   "
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

xml of border.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"

            android:color="#cdcdcd" />
    </shape>
```